# OpenId + Facebook Connect

Tags: authentication, openid, facebook

I have a request for implementing a login system using local credentials + openId + facebook-connect.

So a user could sign up/sign in using any of the 3 possibilities.

I think that allowing OpenId AND facebook connect adds some flexibility, but in other hand adds some restrictions since you have to integrate all different logic and make existing differences transparent for users.

What do you think? Any good reference for managing federated login using both external mechanisms? Any well known site doing it right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RPX](http://rpxnow.com/) lives to take care of the complexity for you.

But if you've made your system able to do any two of the three auth methods mentioned, adding the third isn't that hard.  You've probably already got all the necessary abstractions and workflow elements done.

As for who's doing it... seems like a fair portion of the OpenID-enabled sites I see these days have Facebook Connect too.  I'm not sure which count as well-known...  I guess you could browse [RPX's customer list](https://rpxnow.com/customers).

Comment: I amazed how RPX correlated with Facebook TOS. Data (instead of small set of storable properties) cannot be stored more than 24 hours. But rpx provides "name, email address, gender, birthday, timezone, website, phone number, profile picture, and address" as they say in theirs feature list.

Comment: Well, those things aren't necessarily incompatible, right?  RPX gets the data through the Facebook API, and presumably you're still bound by the same caching rules.